# Intersection of two strings/ sets

Tags: delphi, char, set, intersection, delphi-5

As coming from python I'm looking for something equivalent to this python code ([sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html)) in delphi5:

```
>>> x = set("Hello")
>>> x
set(['H', 'e', 'l', 'o'])

>>> y = set("Hallo")
>>> y
set(['a', 'H', 'l', 'o'])

>>> x.intersection(y)
set(['H', 'l', 'o'])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var
  a, b, c: set of byte;
begin
  a := [1, 2, 3, 4];
  b := [3, 4, 5, 6];
  c := a*b;          // c is the intersection of a and b, i.e., c = [3, 4]
```

But beware:

```
var
  a, b, c: set of integer;
```

will not even compile; instead, you get the 'Sets may have at most 256 elements' error. Please see the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Sets) for more information on Delphi sets.

**Update**

Sorry, forgot to mention the 'obvious' (from the point of view of a Delphi programmer):

```
var
  a, b, c: set of char;
begin
  a := ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  b := ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  c := a*b;          // c is the intersection of a and b, i.e., c = ['C', 'D']
```

But your chars will all be byte chars -- that is, forget about Unicode (Delphi 5 doesn't support Unicode, so in this case this isn't really a restriction)!

Comment: In Delphi 5, I'd go for `set of char` here

Comment: @David: Of course, in the OP's case, 'char' is more relevant. I think the principle is clear, though. But of course, the OP must realise that a 'char' in a set cannot be Unicode...

Comment: Right, and in Delphi 5 with `Char=AnsiChar` that happens not to be a problem

Comment: @David: Oh, I didn't even see that (no tag!).